# Yii: maximizing code reuse with per-user site configurations

Tags: yii

The client I'm working for has a CMS written in Yii.  Currently  a part of their business is customizing the CMS to meet the specific needs of each customer.  About 90% of the code is reused, essentially by copying and pasting from one directory to another.  While I've been working on this project, I've had to merge changes in to the shared codebase several times.

All, or most, of these sites are hosted on the same server, and it would seem that it would make more sense to have a single login, that changed what features we showed based on the login.  In some case that means overriding whole or partial views (eg, the _form.php might change from customer to customer) including the controller and model.  Most of the time, it means adding a new controller for a bit of functionality written just for that client.

I've read about having both a front and backend site  here: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/63/organize-directories-for-applications-with-front-end-and-back-end-using-webapplicationend-behavior but that doesn't seem to be the right fit (I don't want everyone coming to a different start php file, for instance)

Ideally, I'd have users log in, and get assigned a site id, which will filter data in the shared MVC objects, and will add in the ones specifically for them, or override the ones where necessary

Intuitively it seems like something like this would make sense:

Shared controllers go here:

```
/protected/controllers
```

Overrides and additions for client1 go here:

```
/protected/controllers/client1
```

or:

```
/protected/client1/controllers
```

But I'm not sure how to get Yii to do this in the most efficient and easy to manage way.  Is this something that's going to work with Yii, or am I breaking it in ways unintended? If it will work, what's the best way to accomplish it so that it's clear to me six months from now, or some random developer who replaces me?

Comment: what you describe sounds like a mess... i think it would be best if you could make a module _(which has controllers, can manage model/component etc imports)_ per special client or something like that which keeps each client "in his own scope". yii modules can manage their own imports and the module's components can always inherit from the respective application components, which could help with organizing things

Answer (score 0):

Do you know RBAM ?

With Role Based access you can profile your application in more-or-less granular way